# Dynamic upper bound for two-dimensional array

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I'm determining values for a matrix with 92 rows and a varying range of columns (1-64 columns). Depending on the row number, my code should define the upper bound of the number of columns for that row. I am using nested loops, but my code gives me a matrix of 92x64 (so the number of columns is constant).

```
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim o As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim q As Integer
Dim N_bay As Single
Dim N_b As Single
Dim D_r As Single
Dim s As Single
Dim Con_l As Single
Dim tau_s As Single
Dim N_r As Single

D_r = 394.9
s = 4.24
Con_l = 6.1
N_r = 92
N_b = 64

For n = LBound(N_rj, 1) To UBound(N_rj, 1)
    For m = LBound(N_rj, 2) To UBound(N_rj, 2)
        N_rj(n, 1) = n
        N_rj(n, 2) = (D_r - ((n - 1) * s))
        N_rj(n, 3) = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(((D_r - ((n - 1) * s)) / Con_l), 0)
        N_rj(n, 4) = 1 / (N_rj(n, 3))
        size = N_rj(n, 3)
        ReDim N_bz(1 To 92, 1 To size)
            For o = 1 To UBound(N_bz, 1)
                For p = 1 To UBound(N_bz, 2)
                    N_bz(o, p) = p * Con_l
                    Cells(o + 1, p + 6).Value = N_bz(o, p)
                Next p
            Next o

        Cells(n + 1, m).Value = N_rj(n, m)
    Next m
Next n
```

I expect to get a matrix with 92 rows, of which each row has a varying number of columns. Hence, row #1 has 64 columns, row #2 has 63 columns, etc.

Comment: Use a 1D array and assign differently sized arrays to each element of that array.

Comment: Where does `N_rj` get defined?

Comment: Also, your `o` and `p` Loop just seems to overwrite the same values over and over again without doing anything. This is very iterative and that number of writes back to the cells must be taking forever. I'd recommend re-writing so that you only make one write back per `n` loop. One after `Next o` for `N_bz` and then one after `Next n` for `N_rj`

Comment: Dim N_rj(1 To 92, 1 To 4) As Single
Dim N_bz() As Single
Dim size As Integer

Comment: Can you explain what `N_bz` is and what it's expected output should be? At the moment I suspect you're creating a `2D` array and then trying to write it back to a single row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you're trying to do is something like the following

```
Sub MatrixArray()
    Dim m As Long, n As Long, o As Long, p As Long, q As Long
    Dim size As Long

    Dim N_bay As Single, N_b As Single, D_r As Single, s As Single, Con_l As Single
    Dim tau_s As Single, N_r As Single

    Dim N_rj(1 To 92, 1 To 4) As Single, N_bz() As Single

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    D_r = 394.9
    s = 4.24
    Con_l = 6.1
    N_r = 92
    N_b = 64

    For n = LBound(N_rj, 1) To UBound(N_rj, 1)
        For m = LBound(N_rj, 2) To UBound(N_rj, 2)
            N_rj(n, 1) = n
            N_rj(n, 2) = (D_r - ((n - 1) * s))
            N_rj(n, 3) = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(((D_r - ((n - 1) * s)) / Con_l), 0)
            N_rj(n, 4) = 1 / (N_rj(n, 3))
            size = N_rj(n, 3)
            Debug.Print size

            ReDim N_bz(1 To 92, 1 To size)

            For o = 1 To UBound(N_bz, 1)
                For p = 1 To UBound(N_bz, 2)
                    N_bz(o, p) = p * Con_l
                Next p
            Next o

            Cells(n, 7).Resize(1, UBound(N_bz, 2)).Value2 = Application.Index(N_bz, n, 0)

        Next m
    Next n

    Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(N_rj, 1), UBound(N_rj, 2)) = N_rj

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Something like the following might be more efficient though

```
Sub MatrixArray()
    Dim m As Long, n As Long, o As Long, p As Long, q As Long
    Dim size As Long

    Dim N_bay As Single, N_b As Single, D_r As Single, s As Single, Con_l As Single
    Dim tau_s As Single, N_r As Single

    Dim N_rj(1 To 92, 1 To 4) As Single, N_bz() As Single

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    D_r = 394.9
    s = 4.24
    Con_l = 6.1
    N_r = 92
    N_b = 64

    Dim MaxSize As Long
    MaxSize = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(((D_r - ((LBound(N_rj, 1) - 1) * s)) / Con_l), 0)
    Debug.Print MaxSize
    ReDim N_bz(1 To MaxSize)

    For p = 1 To UBound(N_bz)
        N_bz(p) = p * Con_l
    Next p

    For n = LBound(N_rj, 1) To UBound(N_rj, 1)
        N_rj(n, 1) = n
        N_rj(n, 2) = (D_r - ((n - 1) * s))
        N_rj(n, 3) = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(((D_r - ((n - 1) * s)) / Con_l), 0)
        N_rj(n, 4) = 1 / (N_rj(n, 3))
        size = N_rj(n, 3)

        Cells(n, 7).Resize(1, size).Value2 = N_bz
    Next n

    Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(N_rj, 1), UBound(N_rj, 2)) = N_rj

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tom, it works exactly as I want it to. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @user11464106 Great :) Please take a look at my rewrite of it though (just updated again) as I've made a few more improvements. If this has solved your question please don't forget to mark it as solved by clicking on the tick box next to the answer (and upvoting)